# GET запрос с телефона возвращает 404

Tags: nginx, get

```
GET /acquire/callback?orderId=123&lang=ru HTTP/1.1
Host: test.ru
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; SM-G530H Build/LRX22G; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.121 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,en-US;q=0.8
X-Requested-With: com.app.test

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.19.2
Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 05:37:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 555
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

С компьютера все идет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А запрос точно доходит до nginx? Урл верный? Хост верный?

Comment: Возможные причины. 1. Разные хосты (IP адреса сайта) 2. Есть проверка по куке 3. Для мобильных устройств выполняется отдельный скрипт для мобильной версии, в котором есть ошибка. Покажите логи Nginx (отгрепьте), я хочу увидеть в них один и тот же адрес типа `/acquire/callback?orderId=123&lang=ru`, сделанный с разных устройств - компьютера и с телефона.